# Synchronization on Java Method

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a public class called ProcessOrder. Within this class I have a private method called Login(), which logs into another company's system. I want to be able to initiated as many ProcessOrder objects as I want, but the Login() process to be synchronized, which means all the ProcessOrder objects need to wait inline to process Login().

What's the best practice to design my code?

Thanks,

Comment: If you mean you want only one login to be active at a time. then you need to do a class level synchronization, not instance level (like it would be on member function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a synchronized block, specifying the object on which to synchronize on (here, the ProcessOrder class):

```
public class ProcessOrder {
   private void login() {
       synchronized(ProcessOrder.class) {
           // one at a time, please
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I realised just now you were asking for "best practice" - please note the synch above is very far from the "best practice"... if you need to authenticate on a remote service (and since you are not doing it for every call in a fire-and-forget fashion), you'd need to implement some concept of "session", with timeouts and (quite possibly) pooling